# Boot failure on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: boot, kernel, startup, ssd

I was using my laptop with Ubuntu without problem for a few months. I did not update any software or install any OS updates.

This morning when it started, I got

```
error: no such device:....
error: no such disk
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

Then takes me back to GRUB menu. Both Ubuntu option and recovery mode option show the same thing (above).

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Since I did not install anything new, does it mean the SSD is dying (again)? How to check the SSD to and fix any file system errors?

Ubuntu 11.04

EDIT: Just remembered something: when the system was shutting down, it did not turn off. There were a bunch of weird output statements, and I assumed the system had shut down so I turned it off with the power button. Perhaps something got corrupted because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on a laptop. I used a livecd/usb to boot. Did the [grub recovery](http://my.opera.com/seanawake/blog/2010/02/09/grub-2-recovery-with-ubuntu-live-cd-2). But I stopped after the `sudo chroot /mnt` option, and did a `sudo update-initramfs` and a `sudo update-grub`. Then I rebooted, and everything was ok.

Comment: OK, I followed the instructions on http://my.opera.com/seanawake/blog/2010/02/09/grub-2-recovery-with-ubuntu-live-cd-2 . `sudo update-initramfs` doesn't do anything without some options. What is it supposed to do? What are the options? `sudo update-grub` seems to fail with `Cannot find list of partitions! (Try mounting /sys.)`

Comment: I don't think I did much, just `grub-install /dev/sda`, but it is working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok then. Just make the question answered, to remove it from the unsolved problems.